# Разблокировать заблокированные сайты. (Прокси)

Tags: php, веб-программирование, vpn, прокси

Всем привет. Хочу услышать ваше мнения и может быть решения. У нас в стране x (не хочу называть страну) не открываеться ютуб, вКонтакт, интаграм. Люди чтобы зайти в вконтакты включают VPN на своих устройствах и гуляют в заблокированых соц. Сетях. Но у меня есть php хостинг который спокойно загружает html нужной страницы и без сторонних подключений. Можно ли что нибудь намудрить на стороне сервера чтобы он открывал сайты например в фрейме или как то по другому?



Нашел прокси сервер но нормального экзампла как подключаться через прокси не нашел

Comment: пахнет уж точно, но явно не хакерством :)

Comment: @Peresada Хаха. что нибудь посоветуешь?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS

Comment: Фреймом многие ресурсы не позволят открывать, потому что небезопасно это.

Comment: Скорее "Немного нарушение закона". Натяните софт носоков и радуйтесь.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сделать на сервере VPN или какой-то шлюз. Или прокси.

Comment: То есть нужно получить доступы к запрещенным сайтам, так как ваш провайдер их заблокировал, свой сайт вы открыть можете, а с помощью своего сайта, хотите открывать сайты во фрейме любой тематики?

Comment: @nick_n_a да так и есть

Comment: @And да в точности так но не во фрейме а любым способом главное чтобы открывал

Comment: Само просто - сделать http прокси. Но под http  - не откроется контакт и т п. Поэтому.... поднимать SOCKS-прокси. Можно ли его поднять на php- не могу сказать. Если прокси будет поднят на 80-м порту - то будет или сайт, или прокси.

Comment: Еще... нужно учесть, провайдер должен разрешать вашему хосту качать трафик. Он быстро увидит, что "кто-то что-то хорошо качает трафик", и вычислит что это ваш пул. Если вы за этот трафик платите - проблем не будет. Если нет - скорее всего вас обрубят, если много выкачивать будете.

Comment: Пробовали, через анонимные браузеры открывать сайт без вашего сайта?

Comment: @And Через ТОР либо какие нибудь впн подлкючения работают. А мне нужно чтобы простые люди заходили без лишних подключений и программ